# iTextSharp checkbox has value but is not visible as checked

Tags: c#, pdf, checkbox, itext

I need to edit my PDF file using iTextSharp. I have a radio button and checkbox as described below.

I want to have the following: if I put a check mark on the radio button, then the checkbox must be visible as checked.

In the code, the radio button has a value but when I open the PDF file  for the first time, the checkbox is not checked.

When I again put a check mark in the radio button then it turns visible.

Here is my code;

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)); 
AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
pdfFormFields.SetField("4a.0", "1"); // radio button
pdfFormFields.SetField("4a.1", "1"); // checkbox
pdfFormFields.SetField("4a.2", "2010"); // text box
```

Comment: Show us your PDF. It's possible, yet unlikely that `4a.0`, `4a.1`, and `4a.2` are the names of a radio button, checkbox, and text box respectively. I want to double-check. Furthermore, based on what you say, I think that `"1"` is not the value of the **on** state of neither the radio button, nor the check box. In other words: I don't believe you are selecting the radio button with `pdfFormFields.SetField("4a.0", "1");` or checking the check box with `pdfFormFields.SetField("4a.1", "1");` Finally, I want to check for the existence of a `NeedAppearances` flag in your PDF. No PDF = no answer.

Comment: This question was asked by my colleague, who is now on vacation. The pdf in question can be downloaded from https://download.belastingdienst.nl/belastingdienst/docs/garantieverklaring_aanvr_eigenrisicodr_wga_lh4402z4fol.pdf

Comment: The form abuses PDF somewhat. Both 4a.0 and 4a.1 are button fields which have no **Ff** (Field Flags) entry, i.e. for both the flags value is the default 0, which implies that both button fields are checkbox fields as neither the Pushbutton nor the Radio flag is set. But both behave like radio buttons by having multiple kids which in addition to **Off** know no common appearance states. Such use of PDF features is a hindrance for interoperability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*There are both issues in the OP's code causing issues independent of the PDF, and special properties of the PDF causing issues specific to the PDF.*

## PDF independent issues

### Closing the `PdfStamper`

The code provided by the OP does not close the `PdfStamper`. This is required though, without closing the stamper important information will not be written:

```
...
pdfStamper.Close();
```

I assume, though, the OP does close the stamper but merely forgot to copy this line into his question, as the errors I observe without closing the stamper are different.

### Inappropriate `FileMode`

The OP uses `new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)` to create the file output stream. The file mode `OpenOrCreate` is documented as:

```
// Summary:
//     Specifies that the operating system should open a file if it exists; otherwise,
//     a new file should be created. If the file is opened with FileAccess.Read,
//     System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Read permission is required.
//     If the file access is FileAccess.Write, System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Write
//     permission is required. If the file is opened with FileAccess.ReadWrite,
//     both System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Read and System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Write
//     permissions are required.
OpenOrCreate = 4,
```

Thus, if `newFile` already exists, the stamper writes into this file, and if the file the stamper creates is shorter than the formerly existing file, an end piece of that former content remains and effectively makes the PDF invalid.

So please use `FileMode.Create` instead which is documented as:

```
// Summary:
//     Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file
//     already exists, it will be overwritten. This requires System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Write
//     permission. FileMode.Create is equivalent to requesting that if the file
//     does not exist, use System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew; otherwise, use System.IO.FileMode.Truncate.
//     If the file already exists but is a hidden file, an System.UnauthorizedAccessException
//     exception is thrown.
Create = 2,
```

### Append mode

The OP's code does not use the stamper in append mode. For previously signed documents this causes signatures to break. In case of the document the OP shared there indeed is a signature, a so-called usage rights signature. Thus, when opening the PDF again, Adobe Reader shows:

[image: extended features lost]

So please use append mode (or throw away the usage rights signature altogether):

```
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create), '\0', true);
```

## PDF dependent issues

### PDF not exactly following PDF specification

As already remarked in a comment to the question:

> The form abuses PDF somewhat. Both `4a.0` and `4a.1` are button fields which have no **Ff** (Field Flags) entry, i.e. for both fields the flags value is the default 0, which implies that both button fields are checkbox fields as neither the Pushbutton nor the Radio flag is set. But both behave like radio buttons by having multiple kids which in addition to **Off** know no common appearance states. Such use of PDF features is a hindrance for interoperability.

But iText has no problems with this. Still, the PDF should be fixed.

### Hidden values

This is the section of the PDF in question:

[image: Gegevens garantieverklaring marked]

When executing the OP's code one sees that the top element of `4a.0` is marked but one sees no difference in the sub-fields `4a.1` or `4a.2`.

The cause of this is that while the top level elements (radio buttons in `4a.0`) always are visible, the dependent elements `4a.1`, `4a.2`, and `4a.3` (and similarly also the elements dependent on the other top level radio button choices) in the OP's file are flagged as *hidden*, so their value is not shown.

In a PDF viewer the hidden flag of the dependent fields are reset by a JavaScript action of the associated top level radio button when it is selected. Thus, the dependent field values become visible.

iTextSharp, on the other hand, does not contain a JavaScript engine to execute such actions. Thus, those fields remain hidden.

So please not only set the field value but also reset the associated *hidden* flags:

```
pdfFormFields.SetField("4a.1", "1"); // checkbox
pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty("4a.1", "clrflags", 2, null);
pdfFormFields.SetField("4a.2", "2010"); // text box 
pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty("4a.2", "clrflags", 2, null);
```

## All changes applied

The source with all changes is this:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create), '\0', true);
AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
pdfFormFields.SetField("4a.0", "1"); // radio button
pdfFormFields.SetField("4a.1", "1"); // checkbox
pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty("4a.1", "clrflags", 2, null);
pdfFormFields.SetField("4a.2", "2010"); // text box 
pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty("4a.2", "clrflags", 2, null);
pdfStamper.Close();
```

and the result looks like this:

[image: Gegevens garantieverklaring filled in]

Comment: thank you very much! It works. The following code solves it. pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty("4a.1", "clrflags", 2, null);

Comment: @Y.Y. That been said, all the other issues I mentioned are serious, too, and should be fixed, even though they are independent from the reason you asked here.